# SpeechRecognitionEngine recognize words not in Grammar

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, grammar

I'm trying to build a Speech Recognition  program using `SpeechRecognitionEngine`. One of the functions i want to make that i could [google](http://www.google.com) the phrase which I'm telling. I should tell: "Google + my phrase" for example. But the problem is `SpeechRecognitionEngine` only recognizes words which i will add in `Grammar`, so it will not recognize my phrase.How i could accomplish this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

this is possible but is more difficult to implement. basically, you put the system into a constant listening/dictation mode and for each recognized phrase, you choose what to do.

found this answer which you may want to try out as well:
[C# SAPI - Recognizing phrases without pre-defined condition statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618764/c-sharp-sapi-recognizing-phrases-without-pre-defined-condition-statements)

here is a simple example (this is .net 4.5, WinForms), hope it helps

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class Main : Form
{
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine listener;
    private SpeechSynthesizer speaker;      

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        speaker.SelectVoice("Microsoft David Desktop");

        GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
        builder.AppendDictation();

        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(builder);

        listener = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        listener.LoadGrammar(grammar);
        listener.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        listener.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(listener_SpeechRecognized);
        listener.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }

    void listener_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string commandName = e.Result.Text;

        switch (commandName.ToLower())
        {
            case "exit":

                speaker.Speak("talk to you later, bye");
                Application.Exit();
                break;

            case "stop speaking":
            case "stop talking":
            case "be quiet":
            case "silence":

                speaker.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                break;

            case "hello":

                speaker.SpeakAsync("hello, how are you doing?");
                break;

            case "i'm fine":

                speaker.SpeakAsync("i am glad to hear that");
                break;

            case "thank you":

                speaker.SpeakAsync("you're welcome");
                break;

            case "thanks":

                speaker.SpeakAsync("no problem");
                break;

            case "what's the time":
            case "what time is it":
            case "time":

                speaker.SpeakAsync(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

                break;

            case "what's the date":
            case "what day is it":
            case "what is today's date":
            case "what is today":
            case "today":

                speaker.SpeakAsync(DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"));

                break;

            case "do read it":

                Process.Start("http://www.reddit.com");
                break;

            case "do face book":

                Process.Start("http://www.facebook.com");
                break;

            case "do search":

                Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
                break;

            case "do videos":

                Process.Start("http://www.youtube.com");
                break;

            default:

                //handle non-normalized recognition
                Match m = Regex.Match(commandName, "YOUR_PATTERN_HERE");

                if (m.Success)
                {
                    speaker.SpeakAsync("I found a match");

                    //example, probably should URL encode the value...
                    //Process.Start("http://www.google.com?q=" + m.Value);
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //be sure to clean up!
        listener.UnloadAllGrammars();
        listener.Dispose();
        listener = null;

        speaker.Dispose();
        speaker = null;

        grammar = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but It could not understand most words I was saying.  I speak English well with no accent. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current stage of the speech technology. The best you can do is to make the grammar sufficiently large, so you'd feel like all words are recognized, but then the accuracy will degrade significantly.